# Removing NA cases and calculating mean of a factor in R

Tags: r

How can I remove NA cases in a column and calculate the mean value of a factor at the same time?

With this code I calculate the mean value of DC1 in Group_A, within x dataframe

`test.mean <- mean(x$DC1[x$Groups=="Group_A"])`

However, some values of the DC1 column in the Group_A factor do have NA cells. In order to remove NA cases from DC1, I run this code, where the column DC1 is the 3rd.

```
test.filterNA <- x[complete.cases(x[ , 3]), ]
```

How can I merge both codes in one simple line?

Comment: , there is `na.rm` argument in `mean` i.e. `mean(x$DC1[x$Groups == "Group_A"], na.rm = TRUE)`  What is `DC1`?  Is it a numeric column?

Comment: Yes, it's a numeric column

Comment: Or may be `mean(x$DC1[x$Groups=="Group_A" & !is.na(x$Groups)])` or `mean(x$DC1[x$Groups %in% "Group_A"])`  You may still need `na.rm = TRUE` if there are NA values in 'DC1'

Comment: Your first option worked on my data. What an easy argument! Thanks

Comment: Can you try the second and third option

Comment: why not using `aggregate`? like this... `aggregate(DC1~Groups, mean, na.rm=TRUE,data=x)`

Answer (score 2):

Two options from @akrun:

```
mean(x$DC1[x$Groups == "Group_A"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

or

```
mean(x$DC1[x$Groups=="Group_A" & !is.na(x$Groups)])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of options to deal with this situation.  Here, the column 'Groups' is having some missing values.  With the `==` operator, NA values are returned as NA

```
c(1:3, NA) == 2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

When we subset another column based on the logical index above, the NA values will return as NA

If the function to be applied have a missing value removal option, it can be used.  In the case of `mean`, there is `na.rm` which is by default FALSE.  Change it to TRUE and it should work

```
mean(x$DC1[x$Groups == "Group_A"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Another option is to make the NA value to return as FALSE.  This can be done by having another logical condition `& !is.na`

```
mean(x$DC1[x$Groups=="Group_A" & !is.na(x$Groups)])
```

If there are no NA values in 'DC1', it should work fine.  To be safe, it may be better to have `na.rm = TRUE` added as well

---

Third option is using `%in%` which always return TRUE/FALSE

```
mean(x$DC1[x$Groups %in% "Group_A"])
```